# Convert array of arrays, and returns an object with each pair of elements in the array as a key-value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input:

```
var array = [["make", "BMW"], ["model","X6"], ["year",2020]];
```

My Output should be like this:

```
var object = {
  make : “BMW”
  model : “X6”,
  year : 2020
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind using `Map`, that is exactly the format the constructor takes.. eg.. `var m = new Map(array);`.   `console.log(m.make);`  => `BMW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const array = [["make", "BMW"], ["model","X6"], ["year",2020]]; 

let obj={}
for(let item of array){
obj[item[0]]=item[1]
}
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Why create new object in every loop instead of simply assigning `obj[item[0]] = item[1]`

Comment: @adiga modified answer. Doesn't spread operator append new `key-val` pair to same obj?

Comment: You are creating new object literal `{...obj, [item[0]]:item[1] }` and reassigning the variable `obj`. Spread is useful when you don't want to mutate the `obj`. Since you are reassigning back to `obj` there is no need for it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const arr = [["make", "BMW"], ["model","X6"], ["year",2020]];
const res = Object.fromEntries(arr);
console.log(res)
```